# Use a Sequence in a function SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use a sequence inside a T-SQL function but T-SQL doesn't allow the use of `Next Value for`, and `OPENROWSET` doesn't allow me to do queries because of the security of the database.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.newInvoice()
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumberHold AS bigint

    SELECT 
        @NumberHold = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Ten_Seq

    RETURN 
        dbo.sfnSprintf('MyOmnyInvoice[%s]', CAST(@NumberHold as varchar), default);
END
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Your question says "New Value For" but your code says "Next Value For"?  What's the actual error? Why do you need to use `Openrowset`? Please clarify.

Comment: SQL server 2012, I need the "OPENROWSET" in order to bypass the "Next Value For" restriction on the function, by the way is "Next Value For" excuse me for my typing error

Comment: Is there any reason you need to do this stuff in a function? You could put this in a stored procedure instead but of course there are limitations when calling them.

Comment: The idea behind this is use this function with Fluent Nhibernate, so I can manage all the database in code

Comment: Basically - there's nothing you can do in a user-defined function that has side effects.  No newid(), no sequences, no getdate(), nothing that updates the database and nothing that will make the function return a different value on subsequent calls.

Comment: If you can use a stored procedure instead of a function in Fluent Nhibernate, the stored procedure will do what you need.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `NEXT VALUE FOR` function in built-in functions

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx)

**Limitations and Restrictions**

> In views, in user-defined functions, or in computed columns.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use NEXT VALUE FOR function in built-in functions.

**Alternative use STORED PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSeqNextValue3] (@NewNum bigint output) 

AS

BEGIN
  Declare  @SQL  Nvarchar(1000)

  Set @SQL  = 'SELECT @NewNum = Next Value for dbo.IdSequence'
  Exec sp_executesql @Sql,N'@NewNum bigint output',@NewNum output 


END 

DECLARE @id bigint
exec [dbo].[GetSeqNextValue3] @id output
select @id
```